# Sklearn: Difference between using OneVsRestClassifier and build each classifier individually

Tags: scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

As far as I know, multi-label problem can be solved with one-vs-all scheme, for which Scikit-learn implements `OneVsRestClassifier` as a wrapper on classifier such as `svm.SVC`. I am wondering how would it be different if I literally train, say we have a multi-label problem with n classes, n individual binary classifiers for each label and thereby evaluate them separately.

I know it is like a "manual" way of implementing one-vs-all rather than using the wrapper, but are two ways actually different? If so, how are they different, like in execution time or performance of classifier(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would be no difference. For multi-label classification, sklearn one-versus-rest implements binary relevance which is what you have described.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If both ways are identical, does it mean that the final decision of the multi-label SVM doesn't depend on the maximized distance to the hyperplane as multi-class SVM does? That is, when testing, because an instance can belong to multiple classes, seeking a maximized distance to hyperplane is not necessary as we do in multi-class cases. Therefore, in the multi-label scenario like this, the tested instance can be predicted as negative for all classes, while one has to predicted as one of the classes in multi-class scenario.

Comment: The current for the ("built-in") [svm](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC) multi-class strategy is one-versus-one. Thus you will have a difference between ovr and ovo. In multi-label, ovo is called ranking by pairwise comparison. In both case, the decision will depend on the distance to the hyperplane. If it helps you, you can view multi-label classification as several binary classification tasks that are related.

Comment: Sorry I might not have made myself clear. I was focusing on one-vs-rest (OVR) case and was wondering the difference between multi-class (MC) and multi-label (ML) scenario when making final decision. In both cases, OVR breaks down into n binary classifiers, and out of n hyperplanes MC chooses one having the farthest distance from the tested instance as the output while ML simply assigns the instance based on the pos. or neg. signs in each binary classifier and doesn't bother with the distance. If so, the decision making process of ML just described is the same as I did in the OP.